# Parity speed limitations

Tags: parity, nodes

I have a question about the node limitation for mainnet. I want to send a lot of transactions at the same time (let's say 1k), on the ropsten network it queues every tx and send batches of 64 every 10 minutes.

I believe the mainnet is faster, but not sure what would be the limit.
Let's say that the gas price is no problem and will be high.

EDIT: I'm doing some tests on the main network and I'm seeing same pattern... 64tx each 10 minutes. Why is that? Any way to change it?

Answer (score 0):

You should see very similar results on Ropsten and the main net, as they are very similar chains (Ropsten is the test chain that is used prior to a main net fork).

The best way to send large chunks of transactions is to do it with a smart contract. If you are simply sending Ether, you can write a smart contract, fund it with the amount of needed Ether, and write a function that takes an array of address and amounts, and simply sends to each of these addresses. By doing this, you can send ~25-50 (depending on `gasLimit`) accounts Ether in a single transaction.